# Web Audio API Buffer Callback?

Tags: javascript, buffer, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

so im making a gameboy emulator and im on the audio part right now.
basically im pushing samples to a mono audio buffer (1 channel, 2048 length, 22000 sample rate) if it matters.
so im pushing to this buffer, and everytime its full, i play it. but this is causing doubly rusty crackling pops all over. its horrible.

i heard the optimal method is to queue the buffer when its full, wait for the 'internal buffer' to finish playing then play that buffer.
however, i couldnt find anything like that in the api. i was thinking maybe a callback when it finished or anything, but no.

does anyone know if there is anything like that ? or if theres a different way to go about this ?
thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 1):

There is an [`onended`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioscheduledsourcenode-onended) event when an AudioBufferSoruce is finished playing.  This, however, will likely have gaps between when the buffer has ended and when you start playing a new one.  The gap happens because it takes time for the audio thread to notify the main thread that the buffer has ended, and it also takes time for you to receive the event and start up the new buffer.

As you mention the right was is to buffer the data and then schedule the buffer source to start playing just as the previous buffer ends.  Something like the following:

```
s0 = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, {buffer: buffer0});
// delta is a small amount of time, about 3 ms or so to allow for the fact that 
// by the time you call start(), the audio thread may have already incremented
// currentTime.  If it has, the calculations of when the buffer ends will be
// wrong.
startTime = context.currentTime + delta;
s0.start(startTime);

// Create second buffer in buffer1.  Then
s1 = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, {buffer: buffer1});
startTime += buffer0.duration;
s1.start(startTime);
```

`s1` should start playing just as `s0` ends.  There should be no gap between them.  (However, there could be a click or glitch if the last value from buffer0 isn't close to the first value in buffer1.)